# Root partition size remains same after partition resize with gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk-usage, disk-management

I had resized my root partition from 30gb to 70gb using gparted. But Ubuntu still shows that I have the same old disk size while gparted shows that I acually have 70gb and that the other 40gb is somehow used. How can I fix this?

Output of 'df -h':

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        30G   16G   13G  55% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G  8.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           391M  884K  390M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G  284K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   48K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda6       341G  115G  227G  34% /media/Data
/dev/sdb1       932G  459G  474G  50% /media/sidharth/passport
```

Output of mount:

```
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
/dev/sda6 on /media/Data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/sidharth/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=sidharth)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/sidharth/passport type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This resizing was done using an ubuntu live usb. On a side note I realized later that Ubuntu was hibernated while the resizing was done. Might have something to do with that.

Comment: @guntbert: output of df -h and mount posted

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like gparted did extend the partition but not the file system. You will have to do that manually (ext4fs **can** be extended on a running system, even the `/` system).

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda5
```

You will see something like "online-resize necessary" and then (after a few seconds) "the new size is ....".

Check the result with `df -h` once more - you should see the new size.

Comment: For me, I had to `resize2fs /dev/sda1`

Answer (score 0):

For me, after use parted to resize the partition, was needed run:
`sudo resize2fs /dev/<partition>`