# Resized partition with gparted size with df -h

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, gparted

I have Ubuntu server running in VirtualBox. I had an 8GB (default vdi size) and I needed more space so I used a 2 steps method: VBoxManager and an iso with GParted.
I also installed parted on Ubuntu and I get the following message:

```
(parted) print
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 52.4GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  256MB   255MB   primary   ext2         boot
 2      257MB   19.1GB  18.8GB  extended
 5      257MB   19.1GB  18.8GB  logical                lvm
```

The 52GB are added from VBoxManager and only added 10 GB to the already existing partition.

Using df -h I get the following:

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/kvg-root         6.5G  6.2G   52M 100% /
none                         4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                         488M  4.0K  488M   1% /dev
tmpfs                        100M  1.9M   98M   2% /run
none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                         498M     0  498M   0% /run/shm
none                         100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                    228M  156M   60M  73% /boot
```

Only 6.5GB which is the old size.

I saw the answer from here [Root partition size remains same after partition resize with gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329875/root-partition-size-remains-same-after-partition-resize-with-gparted) but I get the following:

```
resize2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
open: Is a directory while opening /
```

or:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/kvg-root
resize2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
The filesystem is already 1764352 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

What should I do so that df -h will output the right values and use the new extra space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into you while attempting to solve this problem.

I think I may may kind of fixed it.
http://pastebin.com/RNE9uC7u

I was looking at this persons pasted output.

Try running

```
 lvextend -L +1G /dev/mapper/kvg-root
```

the +1G is however much space you are adding. Try doing +9G.

then do

```
 sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/kvg-root
```

Comment: I marked your answer as being the right one. A day or two after I asked the question I tried again and I don't remember the exact steps but, I think I also did lvextend and it worked. Perhaps it was a combination of commands, because I know I tried a lot.